# SSAS 2005 put measures in the same folder in excel

Tags: ssas

I created a SSAS 2005 cube and connect to it from Excel 2007. I have a measure group sales. The key of the table is receipt no, line no. Now I create a new measure transactions, which is count distinct of receipt no.  SSAS 2005 automatically assign the new measure in a separate measure group. The problem is in Excel, sales related measures are now in two measure groups (the sales and newly created one for the transactions). I find it a bit of awkward to go to these two folders to drag these measures since they are requested together a lot.

Is there a way to put these measures in same folder? I know there is a folder property for each measure in BIDS, but that will just create a new folder under existing folder for the measure group. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you created a new measure group for the second measure? You control this in BIDS. If they come from the same fact table and relate to dimensions in the same manner, they should be ok in the same measure group

Comment: I can't remember what SSAS 2005 was like, but here's a link about folders in 2008: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dknight/2011/12/20/ssas-display-folders/

Comment: @mmarie For distinct count measures, BIDS creates a separate measure group from the measure group containing other measures based on the same fact table, as this is much better for performance.

Comment: @FrankPI yes the measure group is created automatically. So is there a way?

Comment: @mmarie the measure group is a count discount on a member (receipt no) of the same fact table,so created automatically by BIDS. I have no control over this.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I didn't catch the distinct count part, should have read closer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround would be to make your distinct count measure invisible, and to define a calculated measure in the calculation script that is just replicating this invisible measure, and setting its `ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP` to the name of the main measure group. The `ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP` property of a calculated measure is just use for display purposes, as far as I am aware.